# Duas bases diferentes com spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data

Boa noite

Alguem teria algum exemplo de Spring Data Jpa com duas bases diferentes?
Ex : Postgres e SQLServer em uma mesma aplicação?

Tenho um sistema de necessito consultar uma base legada.

Pesquisando encontrei um exemplo ao qual segui. Consegui fazer o banco principal funcionar mas o secundo não.

Abaixo tenho o passo a passo do que fiz bem como do erro que deu ao acessar o segundo banco.

**1. configurei o arquivo context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/DB1" auth="Container" 
            factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
            type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            driverClass="org.postgresql.Driver"
            jdbcUrl="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.13:5432/db1?useSSL=false"
            user="db1"
            password="******" 
            initialPoolSize="5" 
            minPoolSize="5"
            maxPoolSize="5" 
     />

     <Resource name="jdbc/DB2" auth="Container" 
            factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
            type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            driverClass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            jdbcUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.3:1433;databaseName=db2"
            user="db2"
            password="*******" 
            initialPoolSize="5" 
            minPoolSize="5"
            maxPoolSize="5" 
     />

</Context>
```

**2. Criei um pacote para cada banco de dados com a seguinte estrutura.**

```
>app
  |- postgresql
  |   | model
  |   | repository
  |- sqlserver
      | model
      | repository
```

**3. criei no pacote config uma configuração JPA para cada banco sendo o postgres o principal**

*Configuração Postgresql*

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsuarioRep.class, enableDefaultTransactions=false )
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = UsuarioRep.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);

        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/DB1");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(false);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        //adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        return adapter;

    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(Usuario.class.getPackage().getName());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

*Configuração SqlServer*

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = ColetaEncerranteRep.class , 
                        enableDefaultTransactions=false, 
                        entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactorySqlServer",
                        transactionManagerRef="transactionManagerSqlServer")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses =  ColetaEncerranteRep.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfigSqlServer {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceSqlServer(){
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);

        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/DB2");
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapterSqlServer(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
        adapter.setShowSql(false);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        //adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");

        return adapter;

    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactorySqlServer(DataSource dataSourceSqlServer, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapterSqlServer){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSourceSqlServer);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapterSqlServer);

        factory.setPackagesToScan(ColetaEncerrante.class.getPackage().getName());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerSqlServer(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactorySqlServer){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactorySqlServer);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**4. No pacote config.init coloquei os arquivos de configuração no getRootConfigClasses**

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { JPAConfig.class, JPAConfigSqlServer.class, UtilConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        /*CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter =  new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter};
        */
        HttpPutFormContentFilter httpPutFormContentFilter = new HttpPutFormContentFilter();
        return new Filter[] { httpPutFormContentFilter };

    }

}
```

**5. Criei os models que estão em seus respectivos pacotes conforme item 2**

*Usuario -  bando DB1 Postgresql*

```
@AtributoConfirmacao(atributo="senha",atributoConfirmacao="confirmacaoSenha",message = "Confirmação da senha não confere")
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    @NotBlank(message = "Nome é obrigatório")
    private String nome;

    @NotBlank(message = "E-mail é obrigatório")
    @Email(message = "E-mail inválido")
    private String email;

    private String senha;

    @Transient
    private String confirmacaoSenha;

    private Boolean ativo;

    // demais campos - get e set 

 }
```

*ColetaEncerrante - bando DB2 Sqlserver*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="coletas")
public class ColetaEncerrante implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long coletaID;

    @Column(name="data")
    private LocalDateTime dataDaPrestacaoDeConta;

    // demais campos - get e set 

}
```

**6. Criei os repositórios que estão em seus respectivos pacotes conforme item 2**

*UsuarioRep -  bando DB1 Postgresql*

```
@Repository
public interface UsuarioRep extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long>, UsuarioRepQueries {

    public Optional<Usuario> findByEmailIgnoreCase(String email);

    public List<Usuario> findByCodigoIn(Long[] codigos);

}
```

*ColetaEncerranteRep - bando DB2 Sqlserver*

```
@Repository
public interface ColetaEncerranteRep extends JpaRepository<ColetaEncerrante, Long>, ColetaEncerranteRepQueries {

}
```

**7. Criei os controllers** 
 obs não estão na mesma estrutura de diretório dos bancos estão no pacote controller.

*UsuarioController - banco DB1 postgresql*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/usuarios")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRep usuarioRep;


    @RequestMapping("/novo")
    public ModelAndView novo(Usuario usuario) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("usuario/CadastroUsuario");
        mv.addObject("grupos",grupoRep.findAll());
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView pesquisar(UsuarioFilter usuarioFilter, BindingResult result,@PageableDefault(size=4) Pageable pageable,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("usuario/PesquisaUsuarios");

        PageWrapper<Usuario> paginaWrapper = new PageWrapper<>(usuarioRep.filtrar(usuarioFilter,pageable),httpServletRequest);
        mv.addObject("pagina",paginaWrapper);

        return mv;
    }


}
```

*ColetaEncerranteController - base DB2 Sqlserver*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/coleta/financeiro")
public class ColetaEncerranteController {

    @Autowired
    private ColetaEncerranteRep coletaEncerranteRep;

    @RequestMapping("/conferenciaencerrante")
    public ModelAndView novo(ColetaEncerranteFilter coletaEncerranteFilter, BindingResult result,@PageableDefault(size=4) Pageable pageable,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("coleta/financeiro/ConferenciaEncerrante");

        PageWrapper<ColetaEncerrante> paginaWrapper = new PageWrapper<>(coletaEncerranteRep.filtrar(coletaEncerranteFilter,pageable),httpServletRequest);
        mv.addObject("pagina",paginaWrapper);
        //mv.addObject("grupos",grupoRep.findAll());


        System.out.println("Data Inicial : " + coletaEncerranteFilter.getDataInicial());
        System.out.println("Data Final : " + coletaEncerranteFilter.getDataFinal());

        return mv;
    }
}
```

**8 Teste**

Ao entrar na consulta de usuario, ocorre tudo certo.

Porem ao entrar na consulta de coltetaEncerrante ocorre o erro abaixo.

```
11:19:35.132 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: relation "coletas" does not exist
  Posição: 327
11:19:35.136 INFO  org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
nov 08, 2017 11:19:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "coletas" does not exist
  Posição: 327
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4073)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1237)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2798)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2772)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3401)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3370)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.find(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:241)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.findOne(Unknown Source)
    at app.controller.ColetaEncerranteController(ColetaEncerranteController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Qual versão do spring? Está usando Spring boot? Sua configuração é XML based ou java based?

Comment: No momento estou utilizando 4.3.10.RELEASE

Comment: Não estou utilizando Spring boot , a configuração é Java based.
Retifiquei toda pergunta incluindo maiores detalhes.

Comment: Tinha um erro no programa, corrigi. mas agora vem o erro em questão 
O Spring Data Esta pegando da base principal e não da secundaria

Comment: Se estiver sem resposta a noite tento simular e ver se consigo te ajudar.

Comment: Não consegui nada ainda estou tentando de tudo. Toda ajuda é bem vinda.